# accessing value of a specific key from [NSDictionary] Using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, urlsession

Explanation: I want access Red value from the response below:

```
"data": {
        "id": "193",
        "rootUserId": 359,
        "profileId": 870,
        "name": "flowers",
        "unit": "Kilo-Gram",
        "tags": [],
        "media": "https://onebusinessqrcode.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/e16060cc-9b68-5415-a68c-3880ea16074a.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2021-02-24T12:00:09.534Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-24T12:00:09.534Z",
        "properties": [
            {
                "Jasmin": [
                    {
                        "id": "eb0362a1-231b-4f12-bf10-fb6fcb07f4c1",
                        "value": "Red"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

in my app I have to show "Jasmin" Key from the response so I've typed :

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                        
  if let data = json?["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                          
  if let properties = data["properties"] as? [[String:Any]] {

  for property in properties {

   var object = CategoriesName()            
            
   if let propertyName = property.first?.key   {

   object.name = propertyName
                                        
   let value = properties.first?.values
                                        
   object.value  = value!
                                        
   self.categoryName.append(object)
                                    
     }
                                    
   }
}
```

I have gotten the key successfully.. but I couldn't get (the value of the "id" or "value" correctly of this key -> Jasmin) because it's giving me below when I print the value of Jasmin Key.. I want to get any one of them : (what I really need is to get/print value of value object ex: -> red for a specific key -> Jasmin)

> [<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600002e88d80>( {     id = "eb0362a1-231b-4f12-bf10-fb6fcb07f4c1";     value = Red; } ) ]

my struct is :

```
struct CategoriesName {
    var name :   String?
    var value: Dictionary<String, Any>.Values?
}
```

vars to use it in fetching data :

```
// Received Category Id
 var category_id : String?
 var categoryName = [CategoriesName]()
```

The Whole Request of fetching data:

```
func loadCategoriesName(){
  
var urlBuilder = URLComponents(string: "https://api.yoogad.com/rest/api/v1/profile/store/category/keys")
    
    urlBuilder?.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "categoryId", value:"\(category_id!)")
    ]
    
    guard let url = urlBuilder?.url else { return }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token") as? String ?? ""
    
    request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-auth-token")
    
    // send request
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // error occured
            if error != nil {
       Helper().showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                
                return
            }
            
            do {
                // access data - safe mode
                guard let data = data else {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "Data Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    
                    return
                }
                
                // converting data to JSON
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                
                if let data = json?["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                    
                if let properties = data["properties"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                 for property in properties {
                 var object = CategoriesName()
                            
                 if let propertyName = property.first?.key   {
                  object.name = propertyName
                                
                 let value = properties.first?.values
                                
                 object.value  = value!
                                
                 self.categoryName.append(object)
                                
             }
                            
         }
     }
                     
}
} catch {
       Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                return
            }
            self.pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
        }
        
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: It's because the value of "Jasmin" is an array, do `if let array = properties["Jasmin"] as? [[String: String]] {...`. A better option altogether is to use `Codable` and custom structs so you don't have to deal with all this casting of `Any` typed values.

Comment: it's really a problem using old way of JSONSerialization so could you please show me a better way to acheive that by code using codable if it really will help me to achieve that and solve my problem :'D

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can't access Jasmin directly I need to fetch all keys without writting ex: let array = properties["Jasmin"] as? [[String: String]]  to show them in the app and get all the values of these keys also

Comment: Not sure what you mean, my code snippet was of course not a complete solution but it should easy enough to get values from the array.

Comment: I want to get all keys to show them.. jasmin not a static name it may be changed to another name so I want to access and get them without write jasmin also I want to get all the values of the chosen key may you understand me now @JoakimDanielson